# Routing ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I Have o problem, and i think is because i don't know how to use routing in mvc.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'clientId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in 'LawApplication.Controllers.ClientFolderController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>       Parameter name: parameters

In my application I have a list of clients, and foreach client has edit/delete/details/**Folders**. Each client have a list of folders, and each folder have a list of files/documents. So, i have a controller ClientController and a ClientFolderController.  When I'm accesing Files button, to see the list of folders for a client, I'm using :

```
<button class="btn btn-info">@Html.ActionLink("Folders", "Index", "ClientFolder", new { clientId = item.Id }, null)</button>
```

so i can get the folders for that clientId.
ClientFolderController looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(int clientId)
{
    List<ClientFolder> folder = dbContext.ClientFolders.Where(c => c.ClientId == clientId).ToList();
    return View(folder);
}
```

When i try to add, a new  folder for that specific clientId

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ClientFolder folder)
{
    using (dbContext)
    {
        folder.ClientId = 2;
        dbContext.ClientFolders.Add(folder);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

and the link look like this : http://localhost:55761/ClientFolder?clientId=2

Comment: Your error message suggests `item.Id` is `null`

Comment: what type `ClientFolder.ClientId`? is it nullable?

Comment: ClientId is not nullabale, is a foreign key from Client, type int .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the `clientId` in the `RedirectToAction`

Like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", new { clientId = folder.ClientId });
```

Comment: I just did that, and still not working... return RedirectToAction("Index", folder.ClientId);

Comment: I have another question. (i`m a newbie.. :/) . How can i pass the clientId, when i`m trying to create a new folder?    <button class="btn btn-info">@Html.ActionLink("Add Folder", "Create", )</button>

Comment: Do the same sort of thing; pass the clientId in the ActionLink (which I wouldn't put inside a button by the way).

Comment: ... you'll need to change your Create action to accept the clientId parameter too.

Comment: ... and pass the clientId to the Create view where it can be included in the form.

Comment: 1. I don't  know how to pass that clientId in ActionLink. I`ve tried like this "@Html.ActionLink("Add Folder", "Create", new {clientId= Model.ClientId}" but my model is "@model IEnumerable<LawApplication.ClientFolder>", so i don't get it at all.. and                                                                      2. That clientId that i have to pass in action  you mean Get or Post Action ? :)

Comment: You may need a richer ViewModel to ensure you have the parameters you need on each page. I suggest you follow these tutorials, they should teach you what to do: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started